# writing to LinkedList using Boolean error checking method displays error in another function where parameters are ints

Tags: java, type-conversion, boolean-operations

the error checking method has two checks , first checks if input is integer or string, second checks range of the input, I set check1 to false , if its false then the code goes to the next line. If check1 is true then wrong input is display and user need to do another input.

The issue I Am facing is that when input is correct the value is pushed into Linked List all students and the values for the particular object in the list is integer , so I am getting errors as return from the error function is boolean
any help and advice would be much appreciated

```
 public static Boolean errorChecking(String input) {
            boolean check1 = false;
            int inputConverted = 0;


            try { 
                     inputConverted = Integer.parseInt(input);

                     
                     //Apply second check
                     if(inputConverted>=0 && inputConverted <=100)
                     {
                         return (check1);
                     }
                     else {
                         check1 = true;
                         return (check1);
                     }
            }
            
            catch (NumberFormatException ex )
            {
                  System.out.println("Invalid Input.");
                   check1 = true;
                   return (check1);
            }       
// piece of code where I am trying to apply this function 

System.out.println("Enter Student Mark for English assignement 1: ");
    
    Boolean k = true;
    while (k) {
        System.out.println("Enter number");
        String inputA1 = scanner.next();
        k = errorChecking(inputA1);
        int englishA1 = (k)?1:0;
    } 

addStudent(iD, fName, lName,mathA1, mathA2,mathA3,englishA1,englishA2,englishA3);
```

}

/*the parameters anglishA1 and so on are only two string values rest are all integers , So I am trying to convert the input which could be anything into int , and so far I have tried Integer.Parse() I have tried the method above nothing works

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you're asking. Are you having trouble getting the code to compile? Local variables declared inside the body of the loop won't be visible outside of the loop, so you'll need to declare `int englishA1` before the `while` loop. However, I would expect that you want to set it to the parsed value of the input rather than just `1` or `0`. That would require more extensive changes. Please start by getting your code to compile, then clarify the question with the issue you face.

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi Jamshaid yep you rite , I need to parse the input to int so this is what I 
come up with and it works 
                                 Boolean k = true;
                                 while (k) {
                                           System.out.println("Enter number");
                                           String inputA1 = scanner.next();
                                           k = errorChecking(inputA1);                                           
                                  }
                                int en1 = Integer.parseInt(inputA1);


    addStudent(iD, fName, lName,mathA1, mathA2,mathA3,en1,englishA2,englishA3);
```